# Worklight 6.3 Push notifications stopped working suddenly on Android

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I have setup Push notifications in my Worklight 6.3 hybrid app which was working fine in my Android device until few days back. I didn't make any changes to the app after that. Now when I try to send notification, I get the result as '{"isSuccessful":true,"result": "Notification sent to user :: admin"}'. 
Neither do I see notifications on my device, nor I see any error messages. I also get the 'onSuccess' callback called when WL.Client.Push.subscribe API is executed

Comment: Does this happen in all devices or in a particular decide? If all devices then maybe the dev database is corrupted. Try deleting the mobilefirstConfig folder from your eclipse workspace and try again.

Comment: Why are you not responding?

Answer (score 0):

From your description its seems like the message is sent to GCM and the 
question we need to ask is why it's not arriving the device.

1)Can you please reinstall the application and then try to send push notification? 
If it will work you may have a problem with the device subscription.

2)can you paste here the logcat - maybe we can find something there...

3)Did you try to receive the push when the phone is on WiFi?
If possible please try to check it on a different network.

Sometimes GCM is slow and you might get a notification after about 5 to 10 mins.
if we get isSuccessful":true,"result": "Notification sent to user :: admin 
then from worklight end we have done everything right and GCM has also accepted the notification to be sent.

I will know more once you will upload the additional information